# Bulk update in sql server

Tags: sql-server

If I have millions rows to update in sql server, then how do I proceed? Is there a logical method for bulk update as it will otherwise lock the table for a long time.

Comment: I was asked in the interview recently that how would you update large volume of rows in a production environment as normal update will lock the table for a long time.I could not answer.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code as a bulkadmin user which will mean that triggers won't fire and will make the insert table less time if you have triggers. The down side of this is that triggers won't fire and you may need to have them fire or to write code to do what the tirgger might have done.

You can run the update in batches (of say 10,000) so that you you are not updating millions of rows in one transaction. Make sure each batch is in it's own transaction. It is often best to do this during nonpeak hours as well.

You can make sure your code is written so that it will not update rows that don't need updating. For instance you might see an update statment like this:

```
Update table1
set somefield = 0
```

where you might need

```
Update table1
set somefield = 0
where somefield <> 0
```

There is a huge performance difference between updating a million rows and the 35 that needed update.

If your update is from a file, use SSIS which is optimized for high performance if you write the package corectly.

Answer (score 0):

The interviewer(s) probably wanted to gauge your knowledge of [lock granularity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189849%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  If the "bulk" update would otherwise lock the table, then you could update smaller subsets of the table data, with each one in a separate transaction until all necessary rows were updated.  Smaller subsets of data could allow the updates to hold lesser locks, such as `extent`, `page`, `RID` locks, etc.